# How to set Canvas color from a list of colors in a sequence - Jetpack Compose - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Instead of a random color, how can I sequence through the list of colors so that the color of the canvas cards are always in order?

```
val colorList: List<Color> = listOf(RedOrange, RedPink, BabyBlue, Violet, LightGreen)
val randomColor = colorList.random()

Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .matchParentSize()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clickable { expanded = !expanded }
    ) {
        drawRoundRect(
            color = randomColor,
            size = size,
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(10.dp.toPx())
        )
    }
```

Do not want double colors as seen here:

[image]

Comment: I haven't used Compose, but if you can get access to the index of the item, you could do `colorList[index % colorList.size]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use operator `%` to choose color:

```kotlin
val colorList: List<Color> = listOf(Color.Gray, Color.Blue, Color.LightGray)

@Composable
fun ColorSequence() {
    val items = remember {
        List(10){ "Item $it" }
    }
    LazyColumn {
        itemsIndexed(items){ i, item ->
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .clickable {  }
            ) {
                drawRoundRect(
                    // Use % to choose the color
                    // the color will be color1, color2, color3, color1, color2...
                    color = colorList[i%items.size],
                    size = size,
                    cornerRadius = CornerRadius(10.dp.toPx())
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a separate compose function that creates your canvas and from the fun that you create the list invoke that function from a loop inside the compose column element and use the modules operator according to the size